# Alter mysql event to run only on weekends

Tags: mysql, events

My event runs every 2 hours righ now. But I want to run it only on Saturday and Sundays.

Tried using the weekday() function in alter statement, but I am not sure of the correct syntax to alter the event.
Current functionality: The db event triggers a stored procedure and kicks of every 2 hours.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code for your current event?

Comment: Let it run every 2 hours and test day in code..